# How can I remove multiple printers at once in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

Is there a way to remove multiple printers or devices at once? 
In XP you can select multiple and hit 'delete', but I can't do that in win7. The only thing I can do is right-click and click "remove device" in the "Devices and Printers" folder

And I can only do that for 1 printer at a time. Is there a way to do this for multiple printers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete multiple printers at once, open the console as admin and run:

```
wmic printer where "Local='FALSE'" delete
```

Comment: also, if you set Local='TRUE' it will delete local printers... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible with the default Devices and Printers control panel applet provided in Windows 7. You could give [Device Remover](http://www.pro-it-education.de/software/deviceremover/) a try though:

> **Features**:
>
> - In-Depth view of all installed Devices, Device Classes, Drivers and
>     Services on a
>       Windows System (Hidden, Detached, Current installed,
>     Problematic Devices,etc,...)
> - **Easy On-The-Fly bulk removal of Devices from your System**
> - Modification/Manipulation of Devices, Drivers and Services on the
>     System
> - Live detailed View of Device Detections on the System
> - Huge Device Problem solving Features and Functions
> - Easy On-The-Fly Drivers, Registry Entries and Files Backup
> - And many more use- and powerful Features,...

Comment: it didn't have printer devices, just the underlying device driver
sweet app though!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from a msdos prompt or in the Start/Run window (WinKey+R)

```
Shell:PrintersFolder
```

You will see the old Printers Control Panel where you can delete all the printers you need in one operation.